# How to skip a Grunt target by default

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm defining a Grunt project with multiple tasks and targets, with task `build`, I would like to run some copy targets, and then with task `deployment`, I also want to run `copy` however with some other targets (only copy folder to specific directory for deployment for example), and I don't want to execute this target at `build` task.

So how can I skip this Grunt target from the `build`

Here is my example

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'copy']);
grunt.registerTask('deployment', ['copy:deployment']);

grunt.initConfig(
  {
    copy: {
      foo: // Do something here,
      bar: // Do anothering here,
      ....
      deployment: // Copy file and execute something for deployment target.
    },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'copy:foo', 'copy:bar']);
grunt.registerTask('deployment', ['copy:deployment']);
```

Comment: Thanks @juank, however there are a lot of targets under `copy` task, so I don't want to include all these targets in register `build` task, just want to ignore the `deployment` target from `build` task

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you specify the copy targets for your build task like copy:build for a generic target or like copy:foo, copy:bar.. I don't think it's possible to opt out for a single not wanted target in grunt (unless you create a generic task by a function call)

EDIT:

```
//something like this
grunt.registerTask('copy:build', function(){
  var copyConfig = grunt.config.get('copy');
  Object.keys(copyConfig).forEach(function(target){
    if(target !== 'deployment'){
      grunt.task.run('copy:'+target)
    }

  });
})

grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'copy:build']);
//etc
```

Comment: Creating a generic task would look like : grunt.registerTask('build', createMyBuildTask()) ;

Comment: Could you please help to give me your `createMyBuildTask` as an example? @eimfach